# Unity type or namespace name 'Spatial Tracking' does not exist in the namespace 'UnityEngine'

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, leap-motion

I am working  on this project using a leap motion on a mac notebook.
Unfortunately, I am getting the following error.

[image]

To my knowledge I have the latest versions installed.

Answer (score 1):

The Spatial Tracking is part of the ARCore package.

In order to install it, you have to download the ARCore Unity SDK from GitHub.

You should find `arcore-unity-sdk-1.19.0.unitypackage` here https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-unity-sdk/releases/download/v1.19.0/arcore-unity-sdk-1.19.0.unitypackage.

Execute it and it should be auto-imported in Unity.

Then you'll have you Spatial Tracking.

If you have already installed ARCore/Spatial Tracking, delete plugins and package and reinstall following https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/unity/quickstart-android

Comment: If you are running Unity *on mac*, it should. If you are building a project *for mac*, I'm not sure it'll work.

Comment: I can not seem to find arcore-unity-sdk-1.19.0.unitypackage inside the project  and how do I install it ?

Comment: Now I've added direct link to unitypackage in the answer...

Comment: thank you very much, Any idea on how to install it. I am really new to this

Comment: Are you asking me how to install the package? In order to install the package, you have only to click on it. Otherwise, you can go in Unity, Assets > Import Package

Answer (score 1):

From `Window > Package Manager` install the XR Plugin Management and the error will disappear:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

For those who are working on Windows:

Window > Package Manager and then install the **XR Plugin Management**

At least it worked for me in Unity 2020.1.8 and with the Leap Motion **Core** Package